# which design pattern this project is using in php?

Tags: php, web, design-patterns, backend

im new in php and i'm seeing something new that i have never seen before in my last 2 years experience with c++;
i download a free sample project on internet and the design patter of this web app is pretty cool and new to me and i want to know about it more but i can't recognize which design patter is this.

**information about the project**
for example the pages are in the main folder like this
"login-page.php"

```
<?php include "include/header.php"; ?>
<?php include "include/login-content.php"; ?>
<?php include "action/connection-action.php"; ?>
<?php include "action/login-action.php"; ?>
<?php include "include/footer.php"; ?>
```

and the header and the footer are in "include" folder
and the login-action and connection to the database are in "action" folder and also the contents of the page witch is html and css and alittle bit of js are in the "content" folder
like this

[image]

i don't know if it is a design pattern or not but if it is and someone can recognize it inform me because i want to research about it to learn more.

Comment: This famous design pattern is called "spaghetti code"

Comment: The `?>
<?php` would break any `header` calls in subsequent code. I wouldn't consider this a design pattern, or one that should be studied/followed. I would invest time in studying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller, that is what most frameworks are using.

Comment: The layout of files in the folder structure has very little to do with what we normally thing of as design patterns in code - that's more to do with the way the code objects are structured and the interactions between them. Where the code is physically stored doesn't come into it (although there can be other good reasons for creating a well-ordered system for that too). But in terms of the code with lots of "includes" on every page, that's a pretty old-fashioned way of doing it really.

Comment: thank you for your response @ADyson , as you said it's similar to the old-fashioned way of doing it , what is the cons of this style of coding? i'm interested in this way as a begginer in php but at the same time, i sense it with my heart thta it's a bad pattern to follow .

Comment: Well for example, usually more modern applications might use an autoloader to include all the files from the various application folders into the script rather than lots of "include" or "require" statements. And they might use object-oriented programming and namespaces to compartmentalise the code and make use of different areas where necessary. They might use Composer to bring in 3rd-party libraries in an orderly fashion and keep them up to date. They might follow a specific pattern such as MVC or MVVM, and/or make use of techniques like Dependency Injection etc.

Comment: Although we can't see all the code, this app probably doesn't use many, or any of those, I would guess. That doesn't make it _bad_ per se - lots of very functional sites were (and probably still are) designed this way. It's just that newer techniques can often offer you additional advantages to make your coding more efficient, or re-usable, or whatever. Ideally over time you should make yourself familiar with common / popular patterns and decide how you want to structure each application you write to best advantage for the goals you have in mind.

Comment: @user3783243 Actually, PHP automatically "eats" newlines immediately following a closing tag, precisely so that code like this _does_ work without spitting out accidental whitespace. You can see the effect here: https://3v4l.org/9g4tC

Comment: @ADyson thank you again for more information that you are giving me, i guess in that way it's easier to learn modern frameworks rather that trying to build it from scratch right? and do you have any source to learn how to make a php web app with any good design pattern like mvc ,hmvc , mvvm and etc. from scratch ? i just want to increase my knowledge about it then move to use one them that i more enjoy to work with (the pattern that i most understand :D )

Comment: @IMSoP yeah you are right, this code works fine without any problems and the >? <?php tag is not making troubles (i didn't find but maybe bugs or other problems exist in other parts),

Comment: @IMSoP I don't think that is correct, https://3v4l.org/ubjfX. Maybe a newer version trims?

Comment: @user3783243, it eats new lines, not all white space

Comment: @ChrisHaas I don't see it doing that either, https://3v4l.org/Bf5j3 This also is actually outside of PHP processor so not sure how it could remove that..

Comment: @MohamadrezaHabibzade, there is value in both learning PHP by itself, as well as learning a framework. I am a long-time veteran, and I start most of my major projects with a framework, but when I need a quick script to parse something, I write boring old PHP because I can bend it to my wills easier.

Comment: @user3783243, it only eats one new line, if present: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: @user3783243 You keep adding *extra* whitespace, which is not present in the OP's example. The rule is that it eats **a single newline** following the tag. That's why I included line "d" in my original example - exactly one newline gets output, because the ones **immediately** following each `?>` have been suppressed. (As for "outside PHP processor", that's not how it works - PHP parses the whole file, it just treats things *outside* PHP tags as text to be echoed.)

Comment: @IMSoP or maybe it's just my browser, bringing to other platform doesnt replicate.

Comment: @user3783243 There is **a single newline** between those lines, **which will be suppressed by PHP**. Your last example failed because of all the Warning messages being output. Hide those, and it works perfectly fine: https://3v4l.org/GBKK0